# Переход на другую страницу по нажатию кнопки Войти

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-dom

Есть две страницы:
`/` - главная страница,
`/profile` – страница профиля

На главной странице есть форма авторизации с логином и паролем. После нажатия кнопки Войти должен происходить переход с главной страницы на страницу с профилем, где в теге `h1` должен быть отображен логин. Как это организовать с помощью `react`? Для хранения / отображения логина, нужно использовать `redux`, для маршрутизации - `react-router`.

@WalkMess Как видно из скриншота

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

все располагается на одной странице (по крайней мере визуально).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130994/discussion-on-question-by-humanproblems-------).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cделал для вас быстрый пример.** https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vsem7c
Это не конкретно ваше задание, однако, вы можете изменить состояние по кнопке и вызывать `dispath()`, который передаст данные в store, затем эти данные выводятся в компоненте.

*Так же от состояния зависит войдете вы на страницу или нет.*

**Надеюсь вопросов больше не будет, в этом примере есть все, что вам нужно!**

Comment: а как сделать так, чтобы заголовок `h1` (`Accaunt adminLogin adminPassword`) был на другой странице (не на той, где находятся ссылки Главная, Войти и кнопка Изменить состояние)? Это последний вопрос.

Comment: Он и так на другой странице.

Comment: не знаю на счет кода, но визуально все располагается на одной странице.

Comment: Знакомьтесь: Single-page application

Comment: У вас не будет рисоваться страница с Accaunt, пока auth  не будет  true. Я сделал так, что визуально, даже если auth  false - вы переходите на страницу, но не рисуете ее (в этом отличие), путь указывается, а страница не рисуется. Но вы снова ничего не поняли, начните с простого, прочтите всю документацию на  react, выпишите на листочек все важные моменты, попрактикуйтесь на очень простых примерах, создайте свой первый сайт на react  и потихоньку двигайтесь к  redux. Я не вижу смысла пытаться лететь на самолете, не умея даже в него содится, вы же понимаете, что это невозможно?

Comment: Я знаю, что такое Single-page application. Вопрос в том, как сделать так, чтобы бы было 2 страницы (см. вопрос - `/`, `/profile`)  и на `/profile` выводился бы `h1`?

Comment: я отметил ваш ответ (так как основная идея верна), но все же хотелось бы знать как добиться отображения `h1` на отдельной странице `/profile` (не на странице с кнопкой Изменить состояние и двумя ссылками)? Как я понимаю нужно завести отдельный js файл с компонентом `h1`, но как передать данные для этого в `h1` (в `h1` как написано в вопросе должен содержаться логин)?

Comment: У вас h1  отображается на отдельной части. REACT-ROUTER дает возможность перерисовать страницу так ,как вам будет угодно. Вы не используете страницы, как в  html, вы используете страницу, как component.  Я уже не знаю как объяснить вам это. Пожалуйста, начните изучать  react, просто  react....

Comment: В моем примере вы хоть на структуру смотрели, вы там папку pages  вообще видели?

Comment: я видел папку pages в вашем проекте (там содержится компонент Accaunt.jsx). Я думал, что ссылки в Link (атрибут to) и в Router (атрибут path) позволяют переходить на другие страницы, но в результате получаю, что все находится на одной странице (и кнопка, и ссылки, и содержимое тега h1 - см. скриншот).

Comment: (продолжение) Я не понимаю, как react-router позволяет осуществить переход на другую страницу (со значением логина в h1). Я понимаю, что я надоел (но просто как то сложно дается - **большое спасибо за помощь**). Можете прояснить последний момент  с маршрутизацией, чтобы содержиое h1 отображалось на отдельной странице, а не на главной вместе с кнопкой Изменить состояние.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131012/discussion-between-walkmess-and-humanproblems).

Answer (score 1):

Ну вобщем-то ты должен вызвать функцию которая будет закидывать по клику твое значение в стор, а поже просто вызвать его но странице логина .

```
    <Link to="/profile">
                <Button onClick={setLogin(тут передаешь свой импут)}>Login</Button>
            </Link>
        
        const setLogin = (val) => {
          props.login(val) 
        }
    
      export default connect(
    (dispatch) => ({
      login: (val) => {
        dispatch(Тут твой экшен(val));
      },
    })
)(File Name);
```

Comment: а что вызывается внутри `login: (val) => {dispatch(Тут твой экшен(val))}` вместо экшена?

Comment: Ваш экшен вызывается, который что-то делает с состоянием в  store,  например добавляет  к  state.cash - state.payload.cash

Comment: @WalkMess а что делает функция connect?

Comment: @humanproblems советую вам разобратся как пользоватся react-rudex . тогда все станет ясно .

Comment: @reijkee нашел видеурок https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SYaHe-lP7eY. В связи с ним (в терминах этого видеурока) объясните мне, что такое `File Name` и `Тут твой экшен` в `export default connect(
    (dispatch) => ({
      login: (val) => {
        dispatch(Тут твой экшен(val));
      },
    })
)(File Name);` . Если установить соответствие между вашим кодом и кодом видеурока, то все станет ясно (действительно не хватает для понимания `File Name` и `Тут твой экшен`).

Comment: @reijkee 1. зачем нужно функцию `login` оборачивать в `setLogin`? 2. Каким образом в `FileName` использовать элемент `h1`? 3. Каким образом в action (Тут твой экшен) (в смысле не в том же участке кода, а в отдельном) можно поместить отрисовку компонента `h1`?