# Вывод информации на другой странице с помощью react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, авторизация

Есть код https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vsem7c (см. [Переход на другую страницу по нажатию кнопки Войти](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1343268/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8)

> На главной странице есть форма авторизации с логином и паролем. После
> нажатия кнопки Войти должен происходить переход с главной страницы на
> страницу с профилем, где в теге h1 должен быть отображен логин. Как
> это организовать с помощью react? Для хранения / отображения логина,
> нужно использовать redux, для маршрутизации - react-router.

). Возник вопрос как сделать так, чтобы h1 со значением логина, выводилось на **отдельной** странице `/profile` ( или на `Accaunt`, как в коде) (на отдельной, а **не на той же странице со ссылками `Главная`, `Войти` и кнопкой Изменить состояние**)?

По этому поводу есть свои мысли

> я отметил ваш ответ (так как основная идея верна), но все же хотелось бы знать как добиться отображения h1 на отдельной странице - /profile (не на странице с кнопкой Изменить состояние и двумя ссылками)? Как я понимаю нужно завести отдельный js файл с компонентом h1, но как передать данные для этого в h1 (в h1 как написано в вопросе должен содержаться логин)?

Но как реализовать не представляю (приведите реализацию этого момента).

Answer (score 0):

С React не работал, но чтобы передать данные с одной страницы на другую, нужно воспользоваться свойством [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) или [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).

Там используются обычные пары "ключ-значение", так что проблем возникнуть не должно. Но стоит помнить, что если пользователь запретил вашей странцие сохранять cookie-файлы, то записать что-либо в хранилище не получится.

Пример. Добавить значение в хранилище:

```
localStorage.setItem("login", value);
```

Пример. Взять значение из хранилища:

```
var login = localStorage.getItem("login");
```

Пример. Удалить пару из хранилища:

```
localStorage.removeItem("login");
```

Comment: можете на https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1344848/react-маршрутизация объяснить WalkMess, что он неправильно понимает суть проблемы. Вы же судя по вашему ответу (по первому предложению) меня как раз правильно поняли.

Comment: Просто скиньте ему ссылку на это обсуждение. Если человек хочет понять, он/она разберётся, нет - его/её проблемы.