# React маршрутизация

Tags: javascript, reactjs, веб-программирование, redux, react-router-dom

Есть страница https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fjya8s?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FHeader.jsx. Необходимо, чтобы заголовок h1  с текстом Accaunt располагался визуально на другой странице (не на той, на которой находятся компоненты `Enter` (т.е. должно быть как на https://metanit.com/web/react/4.1.php)). Подскажите как этого добиться (судя по объему кода проблема не большая - но как добиться результата не знаю).

Мне надо добиться эффекта как на https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gs1hLntyczo или как на https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8sQNXH5X7cA.

Comment: @WalkMess я прочитал, что такое SPA. Мне SPA не нужен. Object417 понял меня на https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1344027/Вывод-информации-на-другой-странице-с-помощью-react. Почему вы меня не понимаете?

Comment: Я изменил ваш код и сделал согласно https://metanit.com/web/react/4.1.php - т.е. приложил определенные действия (я лишь прошу меня поправить, чтобы разбросать компоненты по разным страницам)

Comment: На https://metanit.com/web/react/4.1.php показано, что можно сделать 2 или более страниц на React. Я хочу, чтобы у меня было также.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131063/discussion-between-walkmess-and-humanproblems).

Comment: Вопрос в маршрутизации. Я не верю, что нельзя было бы сделать маршрутизацию вместе с redux. Redux не мешает маршрутизации.

Comment: Я использую react-router-dom - import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom'; (см. Header.jsx), а не react-router. 1. Или это одно и тоже?

Comment: @WalkMess а вы полностью просмотрели https://metanit.com/web/react/4.1.php. Видели там компонент  с текстом Главная и компонент с текстом О сайте расположены на **разных (отдельных)** страницах. Вы этот момент видели? Мне нужно именно так. Вся проблема заключена в 3-х последних предложениях.

Comment: @WalkMess Так и компонент Accaunt должен располагаться на **другой** странице, отличной от той, на которой располагаются компоненты Enter и Main.

Comment: @WalkMess Вы поняли 2 моих последних комментария? (их обязательно нужно понять - в них заключена формулировка проблемы).

Comment: Я всё сказал  читайте выше! Мне надоело тут засорять чат флудом.

Comment: @Binatik562 - это логин, блин.

Comment: @WalkMess если не понимаете суть вопроса, то не отвечайте на вопрос, формулировку которого вы не поняли.